# Xbox controller vibration on mobile device - Godot

Tags: android, mobile, godot, gdscript, joystick

I'm developing a game that uses vibration for the Xbox controller. It works fine on PC using `Input.start_joy_vibration()`, but when I'm testing it on an Android device it just doesn't work.

I tried to check the permissions and stuff like that, but none of them worked.

PS: I'm trying to vibrate the controller, not the device on Android!

Answer (score 0):

For Android, you need to use [`Input.vibrate_handheld`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.2/classes/class_input.html#class-input-method-vibrate-handheld):

```
var duration_ms := 500
Input.vibrate_handheld(duration_ms)
```

Comment: Thanks man, but I'm actually trying to rumble the joystick connected to the smartphone, not the phone itself...

Comment: I tested if it was a problem with the joystick, but in other apps it works just fine

Comment: @CaioLuppo I see, I don't know if that is supported. I'd say open an issue on github… Except, I see you went ahead and did it already.